# How to Copy Files on War Start

Tags: deployment, tomcat6, grails-2.0

I have a number for Word Docs and PDFs that need to be copied to a file storage on start of my Grails app.

I figured I can just leverage BootStrap.groovy to check for existing files then copy if none found. However, I don't know the best practice of including the files into the WAR file.

How can I copy these files?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is a best practice, however we have all our `external files` into `web-app` directory. i.e. We have directories `reports` and `pdf` besides `css` and `images` directories. All that files are package and deploy into war file.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid creating resource instances for each file since they aren't referred as such. My files are, however, required by a domain-class.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. Are you talking about creating tomcat resource instance?